# Sending and receiving results from microservices

Tags: python, redis

I welcome everyone. I'm trying to understand microservice architecture.

The task such: is 2 services. The first - for example, books rooms in a hotel. The second is something like a console interface that sends a booking task to the first and waits for a response from him, saying that the room is booked or not.

For this task, I chose redis as the message broker and database. But here's the problem:

To add a room reservation task, for example, you can use list. But... How can the second interface service get the booking result? Booked or not?

What is the best way to use in this situation? It seems like stream also fits here. Or.. pub/sub. But the thing is that both services must both read the channel and write to it, and as I read, the stream is only needed to record any tasks. What is the best way to do this?

Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I think the question is not very clear so my answer will be a bit generic.

If you want 2 microservices to communicate asynchronously using a message broker such as Redis or Kafka use separate topics or channels for each event type. There can be 1 topic for reservation requests and another separate one for reservation saved events. All microservices in the system can then subscribe to these if they are interested in the given event.

I'm not super familiar with Redis, but as I remember you can use its built-in data structures such as the list you mentioned to create queues that can be used for service-to-service messaging. I would not mix storing the actual reservations with this messaging aspect. Use these channels to communicate back and forth and store the actual reservation in another database, table, or dataset.